# what does (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM " in javascript

Tags: javascript

What does the following function mean in JavaScript

```
let Kim =(hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
console.log(Kim);
```

Comment: Run it and you will find the answer

Comment: Thats not a function just 2 statements.

Answer (score -1):

It's a ternary conditional operator - if the hour variable is at least 12, return "PM" otherwise return "AM".

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: It's a conditional operator, not a comparison operator. It isn't a function so it doesn't return anything. And this is a FAQ with many duplicates that doesn't need another answer: [avoid trying to answer questions which... ...have already been asked and answered many times before.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)